# Вырезать первые два символа после точки

Tags: c#

Столкнулся с простой задачей. Нужно вырезать первые два символа после точки в типе double. Например есть число

`price = 26.109000006`
Я должен получить 10. Не 26.10, а просто 10. Без каких либо округление.

Если конвертировать это число в стринг и вырезать первые числа после точки то это делается так.

```
string stringPrice = price.ToString();
stringPrice = stringPrice.Substring(stringPrice.IndexOf(',')+1);
```

На выходи будет 10. Но есть один нюанс. Если попадется число например вот такое

`26.10000000` То метод `ToString()` вернет мне не `26.10000000` а `26.1` и на строке

`stringPrice = stringPrice.Substring(stringPrice.IndexOf(',')+1);` я уже поймаю исключение. 
По идеи метод `ToString()` должен был бы конвертнуть вот так `"26.10000000"`. Но нет, он обрезать нули.

Вообще-то есть подозрение что я вовсе неправильным путем пошел. Моя окончательная цель просто сравнение первых 2-х символом после точки равны ли они `0`. Просто может попасться число `26.0000000005` и тогда на целое число не проверю

Как можно просто получить первые два числа после точки без округлений и обрезаний нулей. Спасибо

Comment: то есть нужно из числа вычесть его целую часть и вывести до второго символа от остатка?))

Comment: `(int)26.0000000005`/`int.Parse("26.0000000005".Split('.')[0])`

Comment: `(int)(price * 100) % 100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То что у вас "не нули" можно проверить так:

`(26.0000000005 - 26) >= 0.01` - false

`(26.109000006 - 26) >= 0.01` - true

Ну или более обобщенный вариант: `(number - Math.Truncate(number)) >= 0.01`

Comment: В таком случаи с числом `26.0000000005` будет ответ false. А после точки идет два нуля `00` и в моем случаи ответ должен быть true. Мне как бы не важно с математической точки зрения больше полное число нуля или нет. Главное проверить первые два символа после точки с нулем. Вот и прибег к конвертации в стринг.

Comment: ну правильно, просто разверните условие и все, в моем случае если нули - false, если не нули - true, поставьте `!`

Comment: @FX_Sektor ну или `(26.01 - 26) < 0.01` - false, `(26.00 - 26) < 0.01` - true